# I dont get value of li of ul using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value of `li` of `ul` using jQuery. Now i got null value. Can anybody give any suggestion?

```
<ul>
    <li id="1" onClick="page()">1</li>
    <li id="2" onClick="page()">1</li>
</ul>

<script>
    function page() {
        var sss = $(this).html();
        alert(sss);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Two pages saying `1`? I assumed that was a typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the current clicked element object:

**DOM:**

```
<ul>
 <li id="1" onClick="page(this)">1</li>
 <li id="2" onClick="page(this)">1</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
function page(obj)
{
 var sss=$(obj).html();
 alert(sss);
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0ycf03qb/)**

Comment: `Unexpected token this` As `this` is keyword in javascript, you can not use as parameter for function

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `this` to the function:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1" onClick="page(this)">1</li>
    <li id="2" onClick="page(this)">1</li>
</ul>
```

```js
function page(el) {
    var sss = $(el).html();
    alert(sss);
}
```

Or alternatively (and preferably) you can use jQuery itself to attach your events:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li id="2">1</li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('li').click(function() {
    var sss = $(this).html();
    alert(sss);
});
```

Comment: Plus 1 for suggesting the *jQuery* alternative. Just saw your edit after adding the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="theList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#theList li').click(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
</script>
```

For a more jquery contained approach

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix jQuery with attribute-based `onclick` handlers. You separate the event handler from the event registration for no benefit (makes it harder to maintain the page). The jQuery way also supports multiple handlers, even for the same event, on the same elements.

Just do it this way:

```
<li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
```

and the code becomes

```
$('li').click(function(){
   var sss = $(this).html();
    alert(html)
});
```